# the background-color of panelGrid doesn't appear in google chrome browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I noticed that the background-color of a panelGrid primesfaces element appeared in internet explorer browser and doesn't work with google chrome browser. please can anybody help me !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<p:panelGrid style="height:200px;width:100%;background-color:#E9F3FF">

    </p:panelGrid>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't run based on source code of server side view technology. CSS runs based on server-produced HTML output. Update your question to remove the JSF source code and include the JSF-generated HTML output instead (in MCVE flavor!). This way `[css]` users will be able to reproduce your problem by just running it as `.html` file and explain the cause and answer the solution.

Comment: Check in the chrome developer tool what **is** used for the background. Might just be that chrome behaves correctly and you are just lucky IE does not.

Comment: @BalusC: I agree, but it does not explain why IE 'works' and Chrome does not.

Comment: @Kukeltje: That's not a JSF problem.

Comment: @BalusC: A, that way, I thought you meant it was included on the PrimeFaces tag in a wrong way

Comment: I have checked it. it used the backgound which I put in the code (style="height:200px;width:100%;background-color:#E9F3FF") but the color doesn't work in google browser
 do you have any suggestions of this problem please